# Using Right( command within a join: SQL

Tags: sql, join

Here's what I've written.  I want to adjust a field to only show the right 4 charaters within the context of a join query (e.g., a.[Plant]=b.right([Location_Code],4)), but it is not working. I must do this in order for the join to work.  Please help (let me know if you need additional details):

```
    SELECT [Plant]
,right([Location_Code],4) as DoorID
      ,[dtmMonthEnd] 
      ,[DealerTIN]
      ,sum([Total_Acts]) as Activations 

  FROM [ExternalDataSources].[dbo].[Nelson_tblActivation_Activity] a
  join [Commissions].[dbo].[vw_MonthlyEarnedCommission_Location] b
  on a.[Plant]=b.right([Location_Code],4)
  where [dtmMonthEnd] = '1/31/2016'
  group by 
[Plant] 
      ,[dtmMonthEnd] 
      ,[DealerTIN]
order by 4 asc
```

Answer (score 1):

The full qualified column name is the *argument* to the `right()` function:

```
SELECT [Plant], right([Location_Code], 4) as DoorID
       [dtmMonthEnd], [DealerTIN], sum([Total_Acts]) as Activations 
FROM [ExternalDataSources].[dbo].[Nelson_tblActivation_Activity] a JOIN
     [Commissions].[dbo].[vw_MonthlyEarnedCommission_Location] b
      on a.[Plant] = right(b.[Location_Code], 4)
WHERE [dtmMonthEnd] = '2016-01-31'
GROUP BY [Plant], [dtmMonthEnd], [DealerTIN], right([Location_Code], 4)
ORDER BY DealerTIN asc;
```

Notes:

- Use ISO standard date formats (such as YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD).
- The use of column numbers for `ORDER BY` is being phased out.  You can use the column alias.

Comment: Works beautifully thank you!  All I needed to do was add the "right(b.[Location_Code], 4)" field into the Group By clause.

THANK YOU!!!!